# How to list POSIX semaphores on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, posix, handle

How can I list the POSIX named semaphores which belong to a specific process on Mac OS X?

I know the `ipcs -s` command but it seems to list the System V semaphores, which I guess is different from the POSIX one since I don't recognize my own named semaphores.

I use the `sem_open` / `sem_close` / `sem_wait` functions.

Is there any way to list the "handles" belong to a specific process, something like the Process Explorer on the Windows platform?

Comment: I would have thought posix semaphores *are* the ones you are using.  What options did you try with `ipcs`?

Comment: I used the ipcs -s command to list the semaphores.

Comment: @GaborForgacs ipcs is only for System V-style semaphores, not POSIX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do `lsof -p <pid> | grep PSXSEM`. `lsof` may be more reliable when run privileged, you may wish to use `sudo lsof ...`.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I'm finding them under `PSXSEM` though, not `PSXSHM`. `lsof` seems to require the PID and does not include them without the PID, any way to get this information for all processes short of iterating over all active processes?

Comment: Oops, yeah, I got myself confused between POSIX semaphores and shared memory. I edited my answer. For me, `lsof` listed at least one PSXSEM without specifying a PID, so it doesn't seem like it's actually required. Did you find a specific system process that uses POSIX semaphores that I could check against? So far, I haven't found any process on my system for which `sudo lsof -p <pid>` lists some but `sudo lsof` without PID doesn't list them. (Haven't bothered to write a test program.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any common OS X software using them, but here's a test program I created: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderOMara/21858c5c93c82bfeb115

Comment: Python uses posix semaphores to implement multiprocessing locks.